# redux dispatch resets other states to default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

#### Summary

I have 2 states: `isLogged` and `counter`. `isLogged` is a bool where the user can set it to true or false, in doing so the user can access certain pages where if `isLogged` is set to true. The `counter` is just a simple int where the user can increment/decrement it. Both states are saved on `sessionStorage` if their values are changed; and on init, I ran a dispatch to get both values from the `sessionstorage`. The default value for `isLogged` is `false`, and `counter` is `0`.

#### The Problem

Let's say for example we have this state values:

```
isLogged = true
counter = 4
```

If I try to call an `increment` action, the values will now be this:

```
isLogged = false
counter = 5
```

As you can see, it resets the `isLogged` to its default value. However when I look on the `sessionstorage` panel on Chrome, it says there: `{isLogged: true, counter: 5}` so it is still saving the values on the `sessonstorage` and everything there seems to work fine. However on the app itself, it says that `isLogged` is now `false` and the user cannot access certain pages anymore even if he didn't logout for some reason.

What's weird is if I refresh the page, the states are now:

```
isLogged = true
counter = 5
```

(of course the data have been fetched from the `sessionstorage`) But if I now switch the `isLogged` to `false`, it will also reset the `counter` to `0`:

```
isLogged = false
counter = 0
```

So the problem is when I call a dispatch/action to modify a certain state, all other states get reset.

#### Codes

`src/actions/index.js`

```
export const increment = (num) => {
    return {
        type: 'INCREMENT',
        payload: num
    }
}

export const decrement = () => {
    return {
        type: 'DECREMENT'
    }
}

export const get_data = () => {
    return {
        type: 'GET'
    }
}

export const signin = () => {
    return {
        type: 'SIGN_IN'
    }
}    

export const signout = () => {
    return {
        type: 'SIGN_OUT'
    }
}

export const getlogged = () => {
    return {
        type: 'GET'
    }
}
```

`src/reducers/counter.js`

```
const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            state += action.payload
            saveCounter(state)
            return state
        case 'DECREMENT':
            state -= 1
            saveCounter(state)
            return state
        case 'GET':
            state = getCounter()
            return state
        default:
            return 0
    }
}

const saveCounter = (state) => {
    const data = {
        counter: state
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
}

const getCounter = () => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("data") != null) {
        const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data"))
        return data["counter"]
   }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}

export default counterReducer
```

`src/reducers/isLogged.js`

```
const loggedReducer = (state = false, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
            state = true
            saveLogged(state)
            return state
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            state = false
            saveLogged(state)
            return state
        case 'GET':
            state = getLogged()
            return state
        default:
            return false
    }
}

const saveLogged = (state) => {
    const data = {isLogged: state}
    sessionStorage.setItem("logged", JSON.stringify(data))
}

const getLogged = () => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("logged") != null) {
        const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("logged"))
        return data["isLogged"]
    }
    else {
        return false
    }

}

export default loggedReducer
```

I'm calling it on a component like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCounter()
}, [])

const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const getCounter = () => {
    dispatch(get_data())
}

return (
    <div className="container-fluid mt-3">
        <p className="text-white">Counter: {counter}</p>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(4))} className="btn btn-primary">+</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())} className="btn btn-danger">-</button>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in both your reducers, you're returning the default state in the default case. This means that every non handled action will reset the states.

For instance, when you dispatch an increment action, it goes in the default state in your reducer and sets the state to false.

The default case should simply return state unchanged.

---

Besides that, you're useEffect seems a bit dangerous, as getCounter changes at every render, it will be called every time.

I would also advise you to use a middleware for redux if you want to save something in the localStorage. A reducer is supposed to be a function with no side-effects so you're not respecting the rule here.
You should also not read from the localStorage via an action but instead read from the localStorage when creating your store.